# How to express cubic (and higher) forms in matrix-vector notation?

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, soft-question, tensors, multivariate-polynomial

In linear algebra we often learn about linear functions
$$f_1(x) = Ax+b$$
And Quadratic forms ;
$$f_2(x) = x^tAx + Bx + c$$
However we could easily imagine arbitrary high level polynomials:

$$\sum c_{i} x_{d_{i1}}^{e_{i1}}x_{d_{i2}}^{e_{i2}}$$
For some lists (vectors) of indexes d and exponents e.

How can we systematically expand to allow for higher order terms ?

I will show **own work** on a cubic term below.
Let us first recursively define
$$\cases{X_k = \text{vec}(x^t X_{k-1})\\\\ X_0 = 1}$$

This way we can rewrite the two first like so:
$$f_1(x) = A X_1 + bX_0$$
$$f_2(x) = AX_2 + BX_1 + cX_0$$
Now following this pattern we can write
$$f_3(x) = AX_3 + BX_2 + CX_1 + dX_0$$
or a general case more compactly:

$$f_n(x) = a^t[X_n,X_{n-1},\cdots,X_0]$$

One really long scalar product.

Is this walking over the bridge for water?

if we instead define

$$\cases{X_k = \text{vec}([x;1]^t X_{k-1})\\\\ X_0 = 1}$$

Suddenly we don't even have to use more than one term. But maybe it gives us other drawbacks?

Are there any widely used conventions for how to write this ?

Comment: This seems messy and inelegant to me. Are you interested in understanding the relationship between homogeneous polynomials of degree $n$ and tensors of order $n$ or do you just want a compact notation for writing down general polynomials? For the latter you can just use multi-index notation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-index_notation

Comment: I want some practically useful way for bookkeeping the data in order to do calculations with them which also has some level of adoptation.

Comment: What kind of calculations?

Comment: Partial differentiation, integration, convolution, linear least squares equation systems on the coefficients. To be able to construct such things in practice I will need some specific order of book-keeping. I have already constructed several of those on my own but it would be interesting to see if I can shift it into more widely used methods or standards.